# Disable button while typing on Input Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want disable a button while I'm typing on input.
But the code below that I 've wrote doesn't work because the button is disabled only when I "confirm" input with keyboard, but **I want disabled input while I'm typing on input**.

```
 TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
 bool isValid = false;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Column( 
      children: <Widget>[
         TextField(
            controller: myController,
            onChanged: (value){
               setState(() {
                  isValid = (value.isEmpty || double.tryParse(value) == null) ? false : true;
               });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
               border: InputBorder.none,
               hintText: 'Enter a search term'
            ),
       ),
       RaisedButton(
          disabledColor: Colors.grey,
          child: Text("${AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("test")}"),
          onPressed: isValid ? () { print("test") }:null,
      ),
    ],
  )
}
```

Comment: you can try to use som plugins like https://github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility but it work on android and ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Also use [**`myController.addListener()`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/addListener.html)

To check result just copy paste below code in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)

> When you enter number in `TextField` the button will enable

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  bool isValid = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up your controller when the Widget is disposed
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    myController.text = '';
    myController.addListener((){
      print("Get Value: ${myController.text}");
      setState(() {
        isValid = (myController.text.isEmpty || double.tryParse(myController.text) == null)
            ? false
            : true;
      });
    });

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: myController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {

              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            disabledColor: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("Click Me"),
            onPressed: isValid
                ? () {
                    print("test");
                  }
                : null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FocusNode`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DemoPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.white),
    );
  }
}

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoPageState createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  TextEditingController textField1Ctrl;
  TextEditingController textField2Ctrl;
  FocusNode focusNode1;
  FocusNode focusNode2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    textField1Ctrl = TextEditingController();
    textField2Ctrl = TextEditingController();
    focusNode1 = FocusNode()..addListener(_rebuildOnFocusChange);
    focusNode2 = FocusNode()..addListener(_rebuildOnFocusChange);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _rebuildOnFocusChange() => setState(() {});

  void _onButton1Pressed() {}

  void _onButton2Pressed() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Disable Button When Text Field has focus"),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: textField1Ctrl,
                    focusNode: focusNode1,
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Button 1"),
                  onPressed: focusNode1.hasFocus ? null : _onButton1Pressed,
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
            Text("Disable Button When TextField is Empty or has focus"),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: textField2Ctrl,
                    focusNode: focusNode2,
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Button 2"),
                  onPressed: focusNode2.hasFocus || textField2Ctrl.text.isEmpty
                      ? null
                      : _onButton2Pressed,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Demo:** [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3c6572667a879309667c8f8b5f8fd49d)